# C# ASP.NET I can't set color on my Gridview when cell is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to change color if `string` is `empty` it set to red color

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
     if (cell.Equals("&nbsp;")||cell.Equals(string.Empty)||string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.ToString()))//if (cell.ToString() == " ")
     {
          cell.BackColor = Color.Red;
     }
     else
     {
          cell.BackColor = Color.White;
     }            
}
```

[[image]]

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string text = cell.Text.Trim();
        cell.BackColor = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text == "&nbsp;") ? Color.Red : Color.White;
    }
}
```